# Trying to run nodeJS application forever on hostgator, even after exiting ssh

Tags: node.js, express, shared-hosting, forever

I am trying to get a NodeJS application (that is, a personal webpage) to run in perpetuity on a HostGator shared server, but no matter what services or background processes I run, the application shuts down as soon as I exit SSH. 
I can run the application perfectly fine up to that point.

I have used various packages through npm including forever, pm2, nodemon, and even the lowly "node [appname] &", but the process simply won't stick. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to make this work? I'm sure other hosting platforms make this much easier, but my domain name and hosting resources are already tied down to hostgator.

Can I perform some kind of configuration? To give you an idea of past steps, my application structure is a modified version of the Node.js Express App project template found in IntelliJ Idea. Also, my .htaccess file on the server is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8093/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8093/$1 [P,L]
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Comment: How do you *want* to run the server from SSH, i.e., what command line?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell to ssh into a shared instance of Red Hat 4.8.2-15 provisioned by HostGator. I don't care so much how the server is run or by what means it's maintained, I just need it to keep running.

Comment: `nohup node [appname] &` will keep it running.

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately. It runs while ssh'd (like the other commands) but stops on exit

Comment: have you tried `tmux` ? it's a linux package I usually use to have something run even when I exit ssh

Comment: @CrazyCoder any luck with that? I'm having the same issue with you. it closes when I exit the terminal :(

Comment: @drake24 I just edited the tags for this question long time ago, I'm not the author and I don't have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you have to go to the directory where your node project is.
- Then run the following command:

  nohup /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/node index.js > output.log 2>&1 &

It will start the Node.js application and redirect the output to the output.log file. The & at the end of the command will run the process in the background.

- Next:

  echo $! > node_app.pid

It will show the process ID (PID) of the running Node.js application. You can capture this PID to manage the process later if necessary.

- Next:

  disown

To ensure that your application continues running after you log out, you can use the disow command.